# Delete entire row

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Sub DeleteRowsIfEmpty()
    Dim myTbl As Word.Table
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Set the table object
    Set myTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(2) ' Modify as needed
    
    ' Get the total number of rows in the table
    rowCount = myTbl.Rows.Count
    
    ' Loop through each row starting from the last row and moving upwards
    For r = rowCount To 2 Step -1
        ' Check if the cell in column 2 (index 2) is empty
        If Trim(myTbl.cell(r, 2).Range.Text) = "" Then
            ' Delete the entire row
            myTbl.Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you get an error or something? Your comments look nice tho.

Comment: It is not showing the result at all, not deleting the rows and not identifying the table just running from start to end

Comment: Are you sure the correct document is active? Are you sure you have the right table? Is it `Tables(2)` ? What happens when you put a breakpoint on the start of the loop and step through it? What is the value of `rowCount` before you execute the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range.Text` of a cell always returns the cell-marker - therefore it will never return an empty value.

Use this little helper function to return the plain text:

```vb
Private Function getCellText(c As Cell) As String
    getCellText = Left(c.Range.Text, Len(c.Range.Text) - 2)
End Function
```

You have to adjust your code:

```vb
If getCellText(myTbl.Cell(r, 2)) = "" Then
```